# How to read .txt file from assets in Flutter?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I have a `.txt` file in my folder assets in the Flutter project and when the app is open on a device a `SQFlite` database is created and should read from this file lines to insert them in the Database. I need to read each line of the `.txt` file and add them to a `List<String>` like this :

```
List<String> _list = await new File('$dir/assets/file.txt').readAsLines();
```

I have try to use `rootBundle` but I can't convert the result as a `File` and by trying to open the file directly like this :

```
String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
```

I always can't find the file and get an error.

```
var byte = await rootBundle.load('assets/bot.txt'); // Can't convert it to file
String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
List<String> _list = await new File('$dir/assets/file.txt').readAsLines(); // Error

error FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/data/user/0/com.example.animationexp/app_flutter/assets/file.txt' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2) during open, closing...
```

Is there a solution for me to open and read this file ?

Comment: Did you list it in pubspec.yaml? https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#specifying-assets

Comment: programatically you can read it

Comment: Yes I have list it in the pubspec.yaml file   assets:
  - assets/file.txt

Comment: @zackattack have you looked at https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files

Comment: @Tinus This link use the getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() as a path and for me this path doesn't seems to work as you can see from the error.

Comment: @zackattack Correct me if im wrong but you are trying to load the bot.txt file ?  the following code looks at file.txt `List<String> _list = await new File('$dir/assets/file.txt').readAsLines();`

Comment: @Tinus It's just a mistake because I have try with a few files

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not working because you just assumed that your `assets` directory is at `ApplicationDocumentsDirectory`, then you joined both directories and looked for the file in a path that doesn't exist.

Instead, you should save your file to disk in a known path, and then get the `File` from that path:

```dart
Future<List<String>> getFileLines() async {
  final data = await rootBundle.load('assets/bot.txt');
  final directory = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
  final file = await writeToFile(data, '$directory/bot.txt');
  return await file.readAsLines();
}

Future<File> writeToFile(ByteData data, String path) {
  return File(path).writeAsBytes(data.buffer.asUint8List(
    data.offsetInBytes,
    data.lengthInBytes,
  ));
}
```

However, if your file is just a simple text file, you should try [Julien Lachal's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3864551/julien-lachal) approach. Just keep in mind that `rootBundle.loadString()` won't work for most file formats.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, it works thank you so much !

Comment: This is how I got a comma-separated array with lines: getFileLines().asStream().forEach((line){
      print(line);
    });

Comment: I've been stuck on this for way too long, thank you for the response

Answer (score 6):

After having declared the file in `pubspec.yml` you could simply get the content using:

```dart
String fileText = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/file.txt');
print(fileText);
```